# Great Caesar's ghost, I smell Bacon

Tags: cipher, steganography

This should be relatively simple for you guys. Spaces and punctuation do not count towards the answer.

It's a quote from a character in a TV Show, but that has nothing to do with what the answer is.

There should be enough here to solve this without hints:

[image: Quote from a TV character]

Hint 1:

> There are two very obvious Bacon Ciphers hidden within this Quote.

Hint 2:

> Bacon Cipher is a bilateral cipher, it uses a series of on or off "triggers" (i.e. normal case / bold case, person looking left in image or person looking right in image, two colors, or any combination of opposites.) in groups of 5. each group of 5 then corresponds to a letter within the alphabet. In this way any message can be encoded into ANYTHING that can represent two opposing signals or triggers. You simply need to find the triggers and figure out the sequence.

Hint 3:

> Caesar is a shift cipher, meaning two alphabets are shifted a number of characters so that each character in one represents a character above or below it in the other.

Comment: This was a satisfying puzzle! I didn't know anything about that particular kind of cipher before this so thanks for introducing it to me and welcome to Puzzling :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> Doctor Who

Here's why:

> When you split up the letters according to Bacon's cipher rules, you get something like this (image in next spoiler):

> [image]

> Grabbing the code from the underlines (bolded in my image) as on/off, you get "ROTTHIRTEEN" and using the differing typefaces (highlighted in my image) you get "QBPGBEJUB" which ROT13's into "DOCTORWHO"